# How to turn tensorflow record into a variable?

Tags: file, tensorflow, data-science

so let's say I have converted 1000 images of dog jpegs into a tensorflow record file (python version, not C++)

Let's say this tensorflow record file has the following path

path = "/Users/Bill/Desktop/work/tensorflowproject1"
data = path +'train.tfrecords'

now the filepath to this tf record file is stored in "data" the string

this is where it gets sort of tricky

---

```
for i in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

This is what the sample on the internet/google website runs on the example they provided "mnist"

But how would I get a variable that represents the training set directly? NOT just the filepath?

I want a dataset within tensorflow that I will then run something like this:

```
train_df = df.sample(frac = .6, random_state = 0).sort()

test_df = df.drop(train_df.index)
```

to split up the data. I have done this a lot with arrays, or dataframes. Never images, or a tensorflow record file

Comment: What format is the data in

Comment: @vogon jeltz:

The data was in jpegs. But I converted it to tf.records

EDIT: tf.records is tensorflow's file format that it works with